# VS, Nuget, TFS - Manage complex internal dependency structure

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget, dependency-management

Due to the number of products we build/maintain, we have a fairly complex dll structure (>100 assemblies). We are in the process of installing TFS 2012. We currently use NuGet to manage references to external dlls.

It appears that Nuget could be an answer for managing our internal dlls.

Here is a sample of our structure:

- Framework.dll
- Business.dll

  - references: Framework.dll
- Business.X.dll

  - references: Framework.dll
  - references: Business.dll
- Application.X.dll

  - refs: Framework.dll
  - refs: Business.X.dll
  - refs: Business.dll

To accomplish this with NuGet, I created a nuget spec/package for each assembly. Each package then includes its dependent pacakge(s).

- Framework.1.0.nupkg
- Business.1.0.nupkg

  - depends on: Framework
- Business.X.1.0.nupkg

  - depends on: Framework, Business
- Application.X.1.0.nupkg

  - depends on: Framework, Business, Business.X

1) I created the Framework VS project, built it, and packaged it to Framework.1.0.nupkg
2) I opened the Business VS project and added a reference to Framework.dll by installing the Framework.1.0.nupkg
3) I then built and packaged the Business VS project as Business.1.0.nupkg
4) I repeated this process for each assembly (FYI, I used NuGetter to automated this)

I'm having trouble reconciling the difference between a local developer machine and the build server.

Here is my understanding:

1. I don't need to store the final assembly in TFS because of NuGet's package restore feature.
2. Instead of referencing an assembly, the reference is added using NuGet. For example, in the Business VS project, the Framework assembly is added from the the Nuget Framework.1.0 package.

However, this makes it difficult for assembly developers to build/test new features. How should a developer working on the Business and Business.X assemblies test a feature locally (on their own machine) without removing/readding references. This is necessary because Business.X references Business that was packaged, not the locally built Business.dll.

My goals:

1. Use a build server to produce versioned, shared assemblies
2. Allow consumer applications to add references to these assemblies
3. Allow developers of shared assemblies to easy compile/test locally before requiring server builds

I think Nuget works well for #1 and #2, but I can't seem to accomplish #3. Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks for any info/pointers!

Comment: Can you not use unit tests to ensure the component is good?

Comment: I agree with @Betty it looks like you simply need some good UTs for the shared asm devs which can be included as a part of their gated checkins

Answer (score 0):

A separate NuGet package per assembly (DLL) is overkill - I'd expect most of your internal NuGet packages to contain a grouping of assemblies which provide a 'chunk' of functionality which is substantially independent of other groups of assemblies.

So this is not the right pattern:

> To accomplish this with NuGet, I created a nuget spec/package for each assembly.

Instead, you might expect to create one or two NuGet packages for each solution (.sln), assuming your solutions are grouped sensibly.